# WPF Handling converter errors and view model validation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, converters

I have an MVVM application with INotifyDataErrorInfo all set up and functioning. Currently I am able to validate all my properties and gate the user from progressing until all errors are handled. Everything was sunshine and roses until recently when we realized that some of our controls (textbox and label combined for displaying digits and unit type i.e. 100mm) weren't displaying the red error decorator when the values were deleted/backspaced.

The control has a converter on it that takes in a double and formats it into a string for display in the textbox. We found a problem in the convertback method where it was sending Binding.DoNothing if the convertback failed to convert the string back into a double. We changed that to DependencyProperty.UnsetValue and figured everything would work fine, but that uncovered a bigger problem.

The problem we are having now is that the viewmodel is not being notified that the converter is failing and I'm not sure how to do that. When a user deletes the textbox content the converter gets called with an empty string. That empty string won't parse out into a double.

I feel like I need a way to inform the VM that the convertback failed so it can flag the property as hasError. I don't see any way to do this though. Here is the code for the convertback method.

```
        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object           parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var strVal = value as string;
        double dblVal = 0;
        bool isSuccess = double.TryParse(strVal, out dblVal);

        if (_systemUnits == SystemUnits.Metric && isSuccess)
        {
            return new[] { dblVal, Binding.DoNothing };
        }
        else if (_systemUnits != SystemUnits.Metric && isSuccess)
        {
            return new[] { Binding.DoNothing, dblVal };
        }
        else
        {
            return new[] { Binding.DoNothing, Binding.DoNothing };
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what other code is pertinent, but I'm willing to post more if you think it would help. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'd suggest converting the property to the actual type of value being typed in (which is text--yes, it's a number in combination with a unit designation, but together it's just text) and validate the contents in the VM.  Cheap and fast.  Other options include creating a special struct that combines a number and a unit, have a static "invalid" value defined (like double.NaN), and return this value when the user's input is invalid.  More complex, but it doesn't give you the shakes as much.

Comment: @Will This was what I was afraid of. Pretty much every workable solution I've run across revolves around changing the property over to a string. It's extremely inconvenient for me but it's starting to look like there aren't many more options.

Answer (score 0):

> I feel like I need a way to inform the VM

Provide a static off of the app class which has the latest instance of the VM in question and in the converter access that static and call a method/property off of it directly to inform of status.

**-Or-**

I would recommend that you create *computed* properties which do the same work as the converters to provide estimates of the failures you mention.

Then you can just access the computed properties and do the process you need to accomplish.

---

Here is an example property `IsOverLimit` which could be bound if needed and checked for statuses via its `INotifyPropertyChange` etc...

```
public bool IsOverLimit { get { return ThreadCreationLimit > 120 } }

 public uint ThreadCreationLimit
    {
        get { return _ThreadCreationLimit; }
        set
        {
            _ThreadCreationLimit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ThreadCreationLimit");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsOverLimit");
        }
    }
```